# Suspension across Spanish competitions?

Tags: football, suspension, la-liga

In the Spanish competition (La Liga), a player will be suspended after collecting five yellow cards. What happens if this player collects his fifth yellow card of a season, but in a cup match (Copa del Rey)? Will he also get suspended, or are these bookings counted separately? Is there any relationship between the different competitions regarding yellow cards?

Answer (score 4):

La Liga and the Copa Del Rey are considered separate competitions, Ronaldo recently picked up a 3 game ban in La Liga against Bilbao but was able to play (and score) in the semi finals against Atl. Madrid.